# Caused by: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/arch/core/internal/SafeIterableMap$ListIterator;

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, uber-api

> Caused by: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/arch/core/internal/SafeIterableMap$ListIterator;

I am getting this error after adding  Uber SDK dependency gradle.

```
   compile 'com.uber.sdk:rides-android:0.9.1'
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile project(':material_search')

    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v13:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:customtabs:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"

    implementation("android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$archRoomVersion") {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    annotationProcessor("android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$archRoomVersion") {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitVersion"
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$firebaseVersion"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$firebaseVersion"
    compile 'com.pixplicity.htmlcompat:library:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.5.0'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.uber.sdk:rides-android:0.9.1'



 minSdkVersion = 17
    targetSdkVersion = 26
    compileSdkVersion = 26
    buildToolsVersion = '26.0.2'
    supportLibraryVersion = '26.1.0'
    retrofitVersion = '2.3.0'
    firebaseVersion = '11.4.0'
    archRoomVersion = '1.0.0-alpha1'
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Use `Implementation` instead of `compile`.

Comment: Already tried but same issue

Comment: Try to remove build folder and run again.

Comment: I have tried that also

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `multiDexEnabled = true` in `build.gradle` file and create an application class. In attachBaseContext method call `MultiDex.install(this)`. And don't forget to declare application class in manifest file. Please refer this https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex. Thanks.